# Resolving JS Syntax Error on Mobile Safari Browser in Odoo 12

Tags: jquery, syntax-error, mobile-safari, odoo-12

### Error: SyntaxError: The string did not match the expected pattern.

**Browser:** Safari (Mobile Device Only)
**File Type:** .js
**Error at this part:** if (a.matches(rulesCache[r].selector)) {

### Thank you very much for taking a look at this code to help me determine the issue.

```
 var css = [];
var style;
a.matches = a.matches || a.webkitMatchesSelector || a.mozMatchesSelector || a.msMatchesSelector || a.oMatchesSelector;
for (r = 0; r < rulesCache.length; r++) {
    if (a.matches(rulesCache[r].selector)) {
        style = rulesCache[r].style;
        if (style.parentRule) {
            var style_obj = {};
            var len;
            for (k = 0, len = style.length ; k < len ; k++) {
                if (style[k].indexOf('animation') !== -1) {
                    continue;
                }
                style_obj[style[k]] = style[style[k].replace(/-(.)/g, function (a, b) { return b.toUpperCase(); })];
                if (new RegExp(style[k] + '\s*:[^:;]+!important' ).test(style.cssText)) {
                    style_obj[style[k]] += ' !important';
                }
            }
            rulesCache[r].style = style = style_obj;
        }
        css.push([rulesCache[r].selector, style]);
    }
}
```

Comment: did you managed to find and answer? im having the same behavior con Safari and Odoo 12

Answer (score 0):

we still haven't found the error's origin (on error rulesCache[r].selector == "@page") but to avoid this we put a try/catch like this:

```
for (r = 0; r < rulesCache.length; r++) {
        try {
            let matchRule = a.matches(rulesCache[r].selector);
            if (matchRule) {
                style = rulesCache[r].style;
                if (style.parentRule) {
                    var style_obj = {};
                    var len;
                    for (k = 0, len = style.length; k < len; k++) {
                        if (style[k].indexOf('animation') !== -1) {
                            continue;
                        }
                        style_obj[style[k]] = style[style[k].replace(/-(.)/g, function(a, b) { return b.toUpperCase(); })];
                        if (new RegExp(style[k] + '\s*:[^:;]+!important').test(style.cssText)) {
                            style_obj[style[k]] += ' !important';
                        }
                    }
                    rulesCache[r].style = style = style_obj;
                }
                css.push([rulesCache[r].selector, style]);
            }
        } catch (e) {
            console.warn("Can't process selector: " + rulesCache[r].selector, e);
            continue;
        }
    }
```

Hope this work for you.
Best regards